# Drupal 8 Headless - Group fields in view

Tags: json, rest, drupal, drupal-views, drupal-8

I am trying to create a REST export in Drupal 8 from a node. At this moment the JSON response is like this:

```
[{
"title": "test 2",
"body": "<p>tets<\/p>",
"created": "10-09-2016 15:57",
"field_first_name": "John",
"field_last_name": "Doe"
}, {
"title": "test",
"body": "<p>test<\/p>"
"created": "10-09-2016 15:56",
"field_first_name": "John",
"field_last_name": "Doe"
}]
```

There are 2 fields, `field_first_name` and `field_last_name`, which are fields from the user who created the node. I wonder if it is possible to group those fields. So the response will look as something like this:

```
[{
"title": "test 2",
"body": "<p>tets<\/p>",
"created": "10-09-2016 15:57",
"user": {
   "field_first_name": "John",
   "field_last_name": "Doe"
}
}]
```

So is there a way to group fields by the entity they are from?